# How to change boolean code to int code in java

Tags: java, string, int, boolean, protocols

I am trying to change some code in my admin panel because of some recent changes in my protocols. What I am trying to do is change the code from boolean to int.

Old Protocol: public static boolean GMSetDoubleExp(boolean)

Here is the original code:

```
try
                    {
                        String dblexp_on = request.getParameter("dblexp_on");
                        if(dblexp_on == null){dblexp_on = "false";}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleEXP(dblexp_on.equals("true")))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved Double Experience Points</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Double Experience Points Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
```

New Protocol: public static boolean GMSetDoubleExp(int)

and here is the code I have now:

```
try
                    {
                        int dblexp_on = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dblexp_on"));
                        if(dblexp_on == 0){dblexp_on = (0);}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleExp(dblexp_on = (1)))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved Double Experience Points</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Double Experience Points Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
```

Even though I get no errors when running the page it gives me an error message saying it hasn't been saved. Any one got any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Here is the full code for my page.

```
<%@page import="protocol.*"%>
<%@include file="WEB-INF/.pwadminconf.jsp"%>

<%
    boolean allowed = false;

    if(request.getSession().getAttribute("ssid") == null)
    {
        out.println("<p align=\"right\"><font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Login for Server configuration...</b></font></p>");
    }
    else
    {
        allowed = true;
    }
%>

<table width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <br>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">

    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center" style="padding: 5;">
            <font color="#ffffff"><b><%out.println(pw_server_name);%></b></font>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;">
            <iframe src="status.jsp" width="120" height="32" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" style="border: 0;"></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            EXP Rate:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%out.println(pw_server_exp);%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            SP Rate:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%out.println(pw_server_sp);%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Drop Rate:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%out.println(pw_server_drop);%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Coins Rate:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%out.println(pw_server_coins);%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;">
            <%out.println(pw_server_description);%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</td>

<td align="center" valign="top">
<%
    if(allowed)
    {
        String message = new String("<br>");

        // ### Apply Changes ###

            if(request.getParameter("process") != null)
            {
                if(request.getParameter("process").compareTo("save") == 0)
                {
                    message = "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved All Values<b></font>";

                    try
                    {
                        int max = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("users_max"));
                        if(DeliveryDB.SetMaxOnlineNum(max, max))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved Maximum User Number<b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Maximum User Number Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Maximum User Number Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        int lambda_value = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("lambda_value"));
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetLambda(lambda_value))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved Lambda Value<b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Lambda Value Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Lambda Value Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        String dblexp_on = request.getParameter("dblexp_on");
                        if(dblexp_on == null){dblexp_on = "false";}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleEXP(dblexp_on.equals("true")))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved Double Experience Points</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Double Experience Points Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Double Experience Points Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        String dblsp_on = request.getParameter("dblsp_on");
                        if(dblsp_on == null){dblsp_on = "false";}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleSP(dblsp_on.equals("true")))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved Double Skill Points</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Double Skill Points Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Double Skill Points Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        String dbldrop_on = request.getParameter("dbldrop_on");
                        if(dbldrop_on == null){dbldrop_on = "false";}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleObject(dbldrop_on.equals("true")))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved Double Droprate</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Double Droprate Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Double Droprate Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        String dblcoin_on = request.getParameter("dblcoin_on");
                        if(dblcoin_on == null){dblcoin_on = "false";}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleMoney(dblcoin_on.equals("true")))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved Double Coins</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Double Coins Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving Double Coins Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        String nomail_on = request.getParameter("nomail_on");
                        if(nomail_on == null){nomail_on = "false";}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetNoMail(nomail_on.equals("true")))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved No-Mail Mode</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving No-Mail Mode Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving No-Mail Mode Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        String nofaction_on = request.getParameter("nofaction_on");
                        if(nofaction_on == null){nofaction_on = "false";}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetNoFaction(nofaction_on.equals("true")))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved No-Faction Mode</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving No-Faction Mode Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving No-Faction Mode Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        String notrade_on = request.getParameter("notrade_on");
                        if(notrade_on == null){notrade_on = "false";}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetNoTrade(notrade_on.equals("true")))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved No-Trade Mode</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving No-Trade Mode Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving No-Trade Mode Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        String noshop_on = request.getParameter("noshop_on");
                        if(noshop_on == null){noshop_on = "false";}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetNoSellPoint(noshop_on.equals("true")))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved No-PlayerShop Mode</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving No-PlayerShop Mode Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving No-PlayerShop Mode Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        String noauction_on = request.getParameter("noauction_on");
                        if(noauction_on == null){noauction_on = "false";}
                        if(DeliveryDB.GMSetNoAuction(noauction_on.equals("true")))
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#00cc00\"><b>Saved No-Auction Mode</b></font><br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving No-Auction Mode Failed</b></font><br>";
                            message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //message += "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving No-Auction Mode Failed</b></font><br>";
                        message = "<font color=\"#ee0000\"><b>Saving of one or more Values Failed<b></font>";
                    }
                }
            }

        // ### END Apply Changes ###

        // ### Get Current Values ###

            String users_max = new String("");
            String users_vmax = new String("");
            String users_online = new String("");
            {
                Integer[] user = new Integer[3];
                DeliveryDB.GetMaxOnlineNum(user);
                if(user[0] == null){user[0] = new Integer(-1);}
                if(user[1] == null){user[1] = new Integer(-1);}
                if(user[2] == null){user[2] = new Integer(-1);}
                users_max = user[0].toString();
                users_vmax = user[1].toString();
                users_online = user[2].toString();
            }

            String lambda = new String("");
            {
                lambda = Integer.toString(DeliveryDB.GMGetLambda());
            }

            String double_exp = new String("");
            {
                byte status = DeliveryDB.GMGetDoubleExp();
                if(status == (byte)1){double_exp = "checked=\"checked\"";}
            }

            String double_sp = new String("");
            {
                byte status = DeliveryDB.GMGetDoubleSP();
                if(status == (byte)1){double_sp = "checked=\"checked\"";}
            }

            String double_drop = new String("");
            {
                byte status = DeliveryDB.GMGetDoubleObject();
                if(status == (byte)1){double_drop = "checked=\"checked\"";}
            }

            String double_coin = new String("");
            {
                byte status = DeliveryDB.GMGetDoubleMoney();
                if(status == (byte)1){double_coin = "checked=\"checked\"";}
            }

            String mail = new String("");
            {
                byte status = DeliveryDB.GMGetNoMail();
                if(status == (byte)1){mail = "checked=\"checked\"";}
            }

            String faction = new String("");
            {
                byte status = DeliveryDB.GMGetNoFaction();
                if(status == (byte)1){faction = "checked=\"checked\"";}
            }

            String trade = new String("");
            {
                byte status = DeliveryDB.GMGetNoTrade();
                if(status == (byte)1){trade = "checked=\"checked\"";}
            }

            String shop = new String("");
            {
                byte status = DeliveryDB.GMGetNoSellPoint();
                if(status == (byte)1){shop = "checked=\"checked\"";}
            }

            String auction = new String("");
            {
                byte status = DeliveryDB.GMGetNoAuction();
                if(status == (byte)1){auction = "checked=\"checked\"";}
            }

        // ### END Get Current Values ###

        // ### Show Form ###

            out.println("<form action=\"index.jsp?page=server&process=save\" method=\"post\" style=\"margin: 0px;\">");
            out.println("<table cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"border: 1px solid #cccccc;\">");
            out.println("<tr><th colspan=\"3\" align=\"center\" style=\"padding: 5px;\">SERVER CONFIGURATION</th>");
            out.println("<tr bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\"><td colspan=\"3\" align=\"center\">" + message + "</td>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Max. Online Users / Virtual Max. Online Users</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"users_max\" type=\"text\" value=\"" + users_max + "\" style=\"width: 40px; text-align: center;\"></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Set Lambda Value</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"lambda_value\" type=\"text\" value=\"" + lambda + "\" style=\"width: 40px; text-align: center;\"></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Turn Double Experience Points On / Off</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"dblexp_on\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" " + double_exp + "></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Turn Double Skill Points On / Off</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"dblsp_on\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" " + double_sp + "></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Turn Double Droprate On / Off</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"dbldrop_on\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" " + double_drop + "></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Turn Double Coins On / Off</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"dblcoin_on\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" " + double_coin + "></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Turn No-Mail Mode On / Off</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"nomail_on\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" " + mail + "></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Turn No-Faction Mode On / Off</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"nofaction_on\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" " + faction + "></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Turn No-Trade Mode On / Off</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"notrade_on\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" " + trade + "></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Turn No-PlayerShop Mode On / Off</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"noshop_on\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" " + shop + "></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\">Turn No-Auction Mode On / Off</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input name=\"noauction_on\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" " + auction + "></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\" style=\"border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;\"><input type=\"image\" src=\"include/btn_save.jpg\" style=\"border: 0px;\"></td></tr>");
            out.println("</table>");
            out.println("</form>");

        // ### END Show Form ###
    }
%>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: int is not really great for tasks like that. You may try [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead.

Comment: Please provide more details on `DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleExp`. What is it actually supposed to do and under what conditions?

Comment: @ lifus - Has been suggested by `Joan` (below) and seemingly acknowledged by OP.

Comment: @PM77-1 That's pretty weird, but I have seen only Madhu Sharan's solution and status was 1 Answer.

Comment: Has **New Protocol** *ever* worked for you or anybody else?

Comment: What it is meant to do is enable double experience on a game server, sorry I didn't see the comments until now. If it will help I can add the whole script to the original post so you can see what it does.

Yes the new protocol has worked for others but they wont share how it was done, nice I know lol

Comment: New Protocol (and particularly `DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleExp` method) - is it **your** code? If so, please post all the relevant parts of it. Ideally you need to create *Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example* - see http://sscce.org/

Comment: No the code isn't mine, I am just editing the panel to get it working with the new up to date version of the server. I've had success so far editing other pages but this one has me a bit stuck. As i said I am new to java, only started learning/working on it 3 days ago.

I have added to full page code to my original post.

Answer (score 3):

the operator for equal comparation is `==` your code should be:

```
if(DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleExp(dblexp_on == (1)))
```

`=` is the assignation operator

if the `GMSetDoubleExp` method is expecting an integer, then you should use:

```
if(DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleExp(dblexp_on))
```

Comment: I gave it go a but it threw an error back at me

    The method GMSetDoubleExp(int) in the type DeliveryDB is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

Comment: Ok, then you just need to use `DeliveryDB.GMSetDoubleExp(dblexp_on)` as dblexp_on is a integer.

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't give any errors but it still isn't saving it and registering as "on"

Comment: whats the value of `request.getParameter("dblexp_on")`? if is not a number it will throw an exception.

Comment: The default value is 0 as the option is turned off by default

Answer (score 1):

@damadboy : i +1 with @Joan. Moreover, instead of changing the whole logic from boolean to int, you can write in a custom function that would take in the input as boolean string and return its int equivalent. That way, it reduces the code hassle and also make it easier for debugging. The function would be something like the one below.

```
private int flagConverter(String flag) {
        if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            return 1; // returns 1 on TRUE
        else if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
            return 0; // returns 0 on FALSE
        else
            return -1; // returns -1 for any inappropriate input
    }
```

Comment: I get quite a few errors when trying this. I'm probably using it wrong but these are the errors I am getting:

'    An error occurred at line: 145 in the jsp file: /server.jsp
    Illegal modifier for the variable flagConverter; only final is permitted
    
    An error occurred at line: 145 in the jsp file: /server.jsp
    Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
    
    An error occurred at line: 145 in the jsp file: /server.jsp
    Syntax error on token ")", ; expected'